# what is the intuition behind equimeasurable decreasing rearrangement of a function

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, decreasing-rearrangements

I am very new to the these topics. I am in a section about Lorentz spaces in Adam's book on Sobolev spaces. What is the intuition in equimeasurable decreasing rearrangement of a function. Given a function $u$ how should I visualize the rearrangement denoted by $u^{*}$? Is it simply about rearranging the values of the function from its highest values to lowest? Any sort of explanation will be helpful.

For example if $u(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ how will $u^{*}(x)$ look like?

The relevant section is in chapter 7 of the book Adams, R.A. and Fournier, J.J.F, Sobolev Spaces, 2nd ed., Academic Press, 2003.

Comment: We'd better add the definition:

If $f$ is a measurable function on $X$, its **decreasing rearrangement** is the function $f^* : (0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ defined by
$$f^*(t) = \inf \{ \alpha \mid \lambda_f(\alpha) \leq t \}$$
where $\lambda_f$ is the **distribution function** $\lambda_f : (0, \infty) \to [0, \infty]$ defined by
$$\lambda_f(\alpha) = \mu(\{ x \mid |f(x)| > \alpha \})$$
where $\mu$ is the measure on $X$.

(Definitions taken from Folland.)

Comment: If I get it correctly, the decreasing rearrangement of a continuous function is like slicing the area under the function in vertical thin strips and the sorting (rearranging) these in decreasing order.

Comment: $\lambda_f$ is like slicing the area under $f$ in horizontal thin strips and slide them so that the left ends touche the $y$ axis. We will then have $\alpha$ on the $y$ axis and the $\lambda_f(\alpha)$ will be on the $x$ axis at the right end of the strip at $\alpha$.

Comment: $f^*$ is almost the inverse of $\lambda_f$. If $\Omega_f = \{ (x,y) \mid y \leq f(x) \}$ then $\Omega_{\lambda_f}$ seems to be the mirror of $\Omega_f$ in the diagonal line $\{ (t, t) \mid t \in \mathbb R \}$.

Comment: I highly recommend you the book Lukas Grafakos on Fourier Analysis third edition